# Can you identify these snowy icicles for me?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Can someone identify the part number for the downard pointing icicles in this scene?:

[image]

If I can get the little groups of 3 snowballs on the roof too, that would be great.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the bricks on the roof are supposed to be smoke from the chimney's not snowballs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Barb / Claw / Horn - Large Flexible](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11089#T=C)

[image]

and

[Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Tooth Vertical](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15070#T=C)

[image]

[Ice Cream Scoops](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6254#T=C)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

[image]

*[Part #11439 - Minifigure, Weapon Sword, Jagged Edges.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11439&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Sword,%20Jagged%20Edges&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=C)*